# I want to know who made changes to the intents, how can I achieve that?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I want to know who made changes to the intents, how can I achieve that? we currently have many users and someone has made changes. We want to know who it was who made the changes. is it either dialogflow or google console from where i can see the changes made

Answer (score 1):

If you enabled [audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/audit-logging#available-logs), specifically "[Data Access audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/configure-data-access#config-console-enable)", you'll see in the [audit log entry](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/understanding-audit-logs#sample) the history of operation made (eg. update intent) and who made the changes. This is visible under Cloud Logging.